# Image Details - Date, realHeight, realWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to get the image details in jQuery. Have dome with W X H, also want to add date too - `realWidth`, `realHeight`, 'Date'.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = $("#img1");

    // Create dummy image to get real size
    $("<img>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function() {
        var realWidth = this.width;
        var realHeight = this.height;
        $('#resolution').html(realWidth + " X " + realHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `load()` is use to make an AJAX request to retrieve HTML content. To hook to the `load` event, use `on()` instead. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $img = $("#img1");

  $("<img />").prop("src", $img.prop("src")).on('load', function() {
    var realWidth = this.width;
    var realHeight = this.height;
    $('#resolution').html(realWidth + " X " + realHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 37px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/3xi2iIl.jpg" id="img1" />
<div id="resolution"></div>
```

Also, I can only assume you need to retrieve the image size in this manner as the image is displayed in altered dimensions in the DOM. If this is not the case, you can read the size from `#img1` directly.